# $scope.$watch Only work once with UI Bootstrap's pagination directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I try to make pagination on my Angular project then i decided to follow this example.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/81fPZxpnOQnIHQgp957q?p=preview
```

Everything works fine except that the $scope.watch only worked once when the data loaded on the first time.
But after that when i click on the pagination link it seems like $scope.watch didn't do anythings.

This is my js code

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'json/multipleOrder.json',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'get',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){

    },
    success: function(data){
      $scope.orderDetails = data;
      $scope.lastPage = data.last_page;

      $scope.orders = data.data
      $scope.getTotal = function(order){
          var total = 0;
          for(var i = 0; i < order.products.length; i++){
              var subtotal = order.products[i].subtotal;
              total += subtotal;
          }
          return total;
      }

      $scope.returnRowNumber = function(rowNumber){
          if(rowNumber === 0){
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
      }

      $scope.filteredTodos = [];
      $scope.currentPage = data.current_page;
      $scope.numPerPage = data.per_page;
      $scope.maxSize = 5;
      $scope.totalOrders = data.total;

      $scope.$watch('currentPage + numPerPage', function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;

        $scope.filteredOrders = $scope.orders.slice(begin, end);
        console.log('end scope watch');
        //Only printed once when the data was loaded
      });

      $scope.$apply();

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest);
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

This is my directive and table.

```
<div class="pagination-box">
        <nav class="clearfix">
          <pagination 
            ng-model="currentPage"
            total-items="totalOrders"
            max-size="maxSize"
            boundary-links="false">
          </pagination>
        </nav>
      </div>

    <tr ng-repeat="order in filteredOrders">
            <th class="text-center">
              <span class="table-order-number">
                <strong>{{ order.id }}</strong>
              </span>
              <br>
              <span>{{ order.customer.name }}</span>
              <br>
              <br>
              <span>{{ order.estimated_pickup }}</span>
            </th>
            <td>
              <span ng-repeat="product in order.products">
                1 X {{ product.name }} <br>
                <span ng-repeat="extra in product.extras">
                  <span ng-repeat="item in extra.items">
                    -- ext {{ item }}
                    <br>
                  </span>
                </span>

                <br>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>{{ getTotal(order) }}</td>
            <td>
              {{ order.customer.address.address1 }}
              <br>
              {{ order.customer.address.address2 }}
              <br>
              {{ order.customer.address.suburb }}
              <br>
              {{ order.customer.address.city }}
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>
                <i class="icon ion-iphone" style="font-size: 24px;"></i> {{ order.customer.phone }}
              </strong>
            </td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td class="text-center">
              <button class="button button-balanced order-bt" ng-click="togglePickupModal()">
                button-balanced
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

But console.log('end scope watch') printed only once.
Nothing happened when i click on the panging link.
How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that `currentPage + numPerPage` is not getting interpreted properly by Angular. Check out what the passed parameters are to your watch and/or just watch `currentPage` as a test. You can make a computed property that does `currentPage + numPerPage` and watch that instead.